# Turn on and off Session in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session

Is there a way of turning on and off the session cookie in ASP.NET without using the <@PAGE construct?  A way to overrule the construct?

I want sometimes to have session enabled on the page, sometimes disabled.  I don't want to have to keep recompiling the website to enable or disable the session.  In php you could turn on session by open_session() , I wonder if there's an asp.net equivalent.  I'm looking for a way to enable the session in code.

If someone visits the Login page, the session is then enabled for the whole otherwise, it is not enabled and the site is sessionless, cookieless.

Comment: What do you mean by turn on and off? What's your goal here? Do you just want to disable session completely and leave it off?

Comment: I want to turn the session on and off in code not a global level.

Answer (score 5):

You must set the Off mode in the sessionState of the web.config file, in this way it disable the session of the application but if you want to disable the asp.net cookie but still track of the session you could use the `cookieless`option.

```
<configuration>    
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
      <sessionState mode="Off"/>
      <!-- or -->
      <sessionState cookieless="true"/>
    </system.web>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: <sessionState mode="Off"/> to disable session.  <sessionState cookieless="true"/> to disable cookie. When you disable cookie, session id will be passed in url

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it in code so I can turn session on and off when the need arises.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can do it in `web.config`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx